# Need to know this XSD pattern meaning

Tags: regex, xsd

Can someone please tell me what the meaning of the following pattern is used in XML.

```
'[A-Za-z\d\-_\s]+'`
```

Comment: It is a regular expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a reg exp
if it is inside the square brackets that means

[Find any character between the brackets]

**A-Za-z this one related to Upper case and lower case only**

**\d\Find a non-digit character**

**\sFind a whitespace character**

+1 or more of previous expression.

This is what it means

I hope this will help you

For more detail kindly read [RegeXp from W3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Thanks

Comment: @user3149750 if you feel the answer is correct kindly click the up vote

Comment: So that means a valid example would be a set of characters followed by a -_?  (jhgj-_)

Comment: @if you like my answer do upvote not only for me when ever you asked question

Comment: if you got the relevant answer

Comment: Not "followed by a `-`". It matches a substring with any of the characters listed in the answer. It can match, for example, `"1-2_Fo o"`